# "// ..." comments at end of code block after } - good or bad?

Tags: source-code, comments

I've often seen such comments be used:

```
function foo() {
   ...
} // foo

while (...) {
   ...
} // while

if (...) {
   ...
} // if
```

and sometimes even as far as

```
if (condition) {
   ...
} // if (condition)
```

I've never understood this practice and thus never applied it. If your code is so long that you need to know what this ending `}` is then perhaps you should consider splitting it up into separate functions. Also, most developers tools are able to jump to the matching bracket. And finally the last is, for me, a clear violation to the DRY principle; if you change the condition you would have to remember to change the comment as well (or else it could get messy for the maintainer, or even for you).

So why do people use this? Should we use it, or is it bad practice?

Comment: In PHP, I use the alternative syntax for control structures `if(condition): ... else: ... endif;`

Comment: @Geoffrey van Wyk - really? I have never seen anybody use these outside of template files. They are extremely unstandard, but to each their own, I guess.

Comment: @Craige: Any language construct natively supported by PHP is not "Extremely Unstandard" -- the PHP interpreter **defines** what "standard" is.

Comment: Ada has specific markers for the end of most constructs: `if ... then ... end if;` `while ... loop ... end loop;` `procedure Foo is ... end Foo;`.  I find that it helps legibility (and it's checked by the compiler, which comments aren't).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would say if you code is so long that you can't easily follow your braces, your code needs refactoring, for most languages.

However, in templating languages (like PHP) it could be valid, because you might have a large block of HTML that separates the beginning and end of the condition or loop structure.

Comment: Completely valid point for PHP, if you're using PHP mixed with Html. 1 point for Gryffindor.

Comment: Even with PHP as a templating language mixed with HTML you can still indent. You also shouldn't use braces when using PHP as a templating language, but rather the `while():` `endwhile;` and `foreach():` `endforeach;` constructs etc.

Comment: I don't really see why you shouldn't be refactoring the PHP. Probably into another language.

Comment: @Htbaa: I can't believe I've been using PHP all this time and didn't know about those. Thanks! Regarding indenting, I prefer to keep the conditional HTML indented the same as the rest of the page, rather than in line with the PHP that's creating it.

Comment: You are welcome. Using them makes PHP templates so much more readable.

Comment: @Tom: I laughed, but feel guilty. :P

Comment: I would consider it valid if it closes something off screen.  It would be better to refactor the code that it is on screen.

Answer (score 20):

It's a code-smell and usually a hangover from old-fashioned code style. Before decent IDEs refactoring was more difficult and not as common as it is now, hence methods were longer and these comments were there to help navigate them better.

Answer (score 15):

This is a horrible practice made obsolete by many factors.

- Most modern IDE's highlight the corresponding brace when the caret is on either symbol.
- If you're coding cleanly, you'll rarely find a place where your method is more than 10 lines.

I notice a lot of Java programmers having this mindset, and it makes the Java code look really dirty and takes the focus away from the code and towards the comments.

**Highly** suggest against using this.

Comment: I have a coworker (java developer) who does this.  Except instead of //for and //if he uses //rof and //fi.  It drives me crazy and he does it everywhere.

Comment: Yeah I had one that insisted on it. AAAAAGHHHHH.

Comment: This really does not have anything to do with Java or Java programmers, and it's not common or a de-facto standard thing to do when programming in Java.

Comment: +1,000 for "is a horrible practice".

Answer (score 7):

Code is read 10 times more than it's written.

If it makes it easier to read, do it.

I'd also suggest to anyone doing this that they should look at some other ways to make things easier to read. The refactoring techniques, brackets on different lines, etc. that other people have mentioned are all good. Splitting things out into different functions, methods or classes so that the code is self-commenting is also good. There are also ways of eliminating most "ifs" and putting "for" loops into obvious places, thus eliminating the need for any of this.

But, sometimes people are learning. If this is something they're doing that's genuinely making the code more readable, encourage it, and then encourage some other practices too. People who are learning deserve and will benefit from encouragement, regardless of how they start. Saying "This is bad" isn't as useful as saying "This other thing is better".

Comment: This *is* bad. Even beginner level textbooks don't do this atrocity. "Code is read 10 times more than it's written"... all the more reason not to waste the reader's time with this code cruft.

Comment: @trinithis What if you have 20-case switch statement? Sometimes you need to support 20 different options, and it's better to have them gathered in one place than "refactored" into some multi-level decision-making scheme.

Comment: i believe this is a practice by coders who underestimate peers :) that others are not smarter enough to read the code unless. gnerally i am against this practice, but okay if someone does it coz there is a jungle of }s that makes it hardly readable. i dont do that anyways!

Comment: @trinithis It's not about whether it's bad or not, it's about effective ways to help people get better so they grow through it. Being effective > being right. It's also a perfectly sensible thing to do if, say, you're refactoring legacy code that's even more of a mess. Sometimes bad things can make better interim steps and lead to something even better than that.

Comment: My opinion is that if the code is complex enough to warrent the `// end if` (or `// end BLANK`) comment, the code is complex enough that I would have no idea what control structure any line of code belongs to. Therefore each line of code should have a comment telling the reader where the code resides: `if(x == y) { // in void bar(int x) <newline> doSomething1(); // in if(x == y) <newline> doSomething2(); //in if(x == y) <newline> } // end if(x == y) <newline> ++x; // in void bar(int x)`

Comment: @trinithis Sorry, I can't work out what you mean when it's all on one line like that. I think I mentioned that there are also other ways of refactoring code that devs doing this could learn.

Answer (score 5):

In C++ there are two holdovers where this is still useful and the advice of "split up your code" doesn't necessary hold:

1. For namespaces.  A namespace can encompass an entire file, and that last bracket can sometimes throw people off, so adding a comment to indicate the bracket is the closing of a namespace is useful.  For the particular coding style at my company this is important because we do not indent namespaces as it was decided that such indentation would just waste space in a file.
2. For #ifdef / #endif pairs.  Sometimes there's a lot of code in there for conditional compilation, it can get nasty with nesting, and the editor we use often heavy-handedly "helpfully" eliminates indentation, so the comments are useful during a quick overview.

Comment: +1 for the namespace comment and the reasons. That's the only time I do this and for the same reason

Comment: + long switch statements.

Answer (score 4):

I've got a large (C++) code base full of this sort of thing:

```
int Class::AccessorMethod(void)
{
    return privateValue;
}//end AccessorMethod
```

For something this small, I'd say this goes beyond "code smell" into "code stink".  Especially in an IDE where I can match the closing brace with a keystroke to find the opening brace.  Given a longer method, I'll still take the brace matching over the terminal comment.  Such comments distract me, and I tend to think of them as noise.

Comment: Um, I guess I don't get some of the formatting on this site; each brace up there should be on its own line, as should the method body.

Comment: In C++ though I will often open anonymous namespace at the top for hidden implementation stuff. Then at some point I close this brace and it's useful to know what the close-brace means here.

Answer (score 1):

For me the code has to be confusing to add a comment like that which you specified.

If it just says // IF Statement.  Then you got to wonder why it's there in the first place.

Comment: I agree, it looks like a line that's been commented out, rather than an old school `//endif`

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to seeing what your brace is closing is having the opening one on the same column as the close one. I find that much clearer and more readable.

The comment is useful when it would normally be hard to trace because the open happened a long time ago. This should normally happen only for a namespace (particularly the anonymous one in C++, used for implementation detail in the compilation unit). In most other cases it should be obvious what you are closing.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely a holdover from the old days of working in 80x24 character terminal windows, especially if you were using a windowed editor like EVE.  Even now, I do most of my work in a terminal session using vim, and I may split the session into three or four subwindows, so I can only really view a few lines at any one time.

That said, I never really warmed to the convention, even though it would have saved my bacon on more than one occasion.  I just see it as noise.  If your loops or conditionals are getting that big, yeah, you might want to look into refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

you basically give all valid reasons why not to use this. Every decent programmer should apply these. So why *do* people use it? Because they are doing it wrong and do not know better.

Comment: erm, explain the downvote please. I didn't just invent this answer, it stems from a real life experience: my collegue who's sitting a couple of feet next to me has been programming for over 10 ears like that and had no clue about why this is wrong until I explained him.

Comment: Possibly it was used in some textbook so a bunch of people came out of college using it? It could have a place in an introductory text.  Also reasonably valid in a preprocessor, especially in #ifdef/endif include guards